# 500 Internal Server Error in store page

Tags: error, overrides, upgrade, class, http-error-500

I recently updated my Magento from 1.4 to 1.9 and faced with the issue: it gives HTTP-header 500 Internal Server Error, but all **the content is still loading** (so just instead `200 OK` I have `500 Internal Server Error`).

It's interesting, that the CMS pages comes with `200 OK`. The problem is exists only within the store pages (i. e. catalog, product, etc).

What have I tried:

- temporarily removed .htaccess
- double checked the config table's the proper paths
- tried all the solutions suggested in [this article](http://techjam.gr/2012/magento/solve-magento-500-internal-server-errors/) as well as [this one](http://www.learnmagento.org/magento-tips-tricks/magento-fix-500-internal-server-error-magento-installation/)
- disabled all the custom modules

**Update:**

I looked on the logfile and noticed that it shows the following PHP Fatal Error:
`Cannot redeclare class Mage_Catalog_Model_Product in /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php on line 2073`

To catch this error I've put on the beginning of this file before the class declaration the following code:

```
if ( class_exists( 'Mage_Catalog_Model_Product', FALSE ) ) {
    $reflector = new ReflectionClass( 'Mage_Catalog_Model_Product' );
    Mage::log($reflector->getFileName(),Zend_log::DEBUG );
}
```

which showed this line:
`2014-09-07T08:42:47+00:00 DEBUG (7): /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php`

So, as far as I understand, the class **redeclares** in the same php file! How to avoid that?

Comment: Are you seeing any errors being reported in php error logs ?

Comment: @JamesCowie thanks for your comment, I've updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've solved the issue by removing the line `include('Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php');` from my rewriting class.

So probably now it isn't necessary for class rewriting because of autoloading system.